# How to show results of SQL aggregate functions in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to calculate various SQL analytics and finally store them as key value.

For example

```
Select col1, col2, sum(col3),
count(col4)
From Table
Group by col1,col2
```

Result

```
Col1 | col2 | sum(col3) | count(col4)
   X |   Y  |     5     |     10
```

But I want the result in the format

```
Key                          | Value
-----------------------------+------
Concat ( col1,col2, "sum")   |   5
Concat (col1,col2, " count") |  10
```

Can someone please help me with it.

Thanks

Comment: You almost have the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform `UNPIVOT`. [Here is](http://blog.devart.com/is-unpivot-the-best-way-for-converting-columns-into-rows.html) one of the many articles on this topic.

As you correctly said, `UNION ALL` would need to run the query several times.

Here is one possible way to do it while calculating aggregated values only once.
[See also SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d6c4/2/0)

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(col1 varchar(50), col2 varchar(50), col3 int, col4 int);

INSERT INTO @T(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES 
('X', 'Y', 1, 10),
('X', 'Y', 2, 20),
('X', 'Y', 3, 30),
('X', 'Y', 4, 40),
('X', 'Y', 5, 50),
('A', 'B', 1, 10),
('A', 'B', 2, 20),
('A', 'B', 3, 30);

SELECT
    col1
    ,col2
    ,SUM(col3) AS SumCol3
    ,COUNT(col4) AS CountCol4
FROM @T
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

**Result of simple grouping**

```
col1    col2    SumCol3    CountCol4
A       B       6          3
X       Y       15         5
```

**Group and then UNPIVOT results** by joining to the table with two rows `(sum, count)`.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        col1
        ,col2
        ,SUM(col3) AS SumCol3
        ,COUNT(col4) AS CountCol4
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY col1, col2
)
,FunctionNames
AS
(
    SELECT ID, FunctionName
    FROM (VALUES (1, 'sum'),(2, 'count') )AS t(ID, FunctionName)
)
SELECT
    CTE.col1 + '_' + CTE.col2 + '_' + FunctionNames.FunctionName AS KeyName
    ,CASE
    WHEN FunctionNames.ID = 1 THEN CTE.SumCol3
    WHEN FunctionNames.ID = 2 THEN CTE.CountCol4
    END AS Value
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS JOIN FunctionNames
ORDER BY
    CTE.col1
    ,CTE.col2
    ,FunctionNames.ID;
```

**final result set**

```
KeyName      Value
A_B_sum      6
A_B_count    3
X_Y_sum      15
X_Y_count    5
```

[image: unpivot]

You can see in the plan that the main table `@T` in scanned and sorted only once and that aggregate is calculated only once.

**Using UNION ALL**

The query that uses `UNION ALL` produces same results (with slightly different sorting), but you can see in the execution plan, that the main table was scanned and sorted twice.

```
SELECT
    col1 + '_' + col2 + '_sum' AS KeyName
    ,SUM(col3) AS Value
FROM @T
GROUP BY col1, col2

UNION ALL

SELECT
    col1 + '_' + col2 + '_count' AS KeyName
    ,COUNT(col4) AS Value
FROM @T
GROUP BY col1, col2

ORDER BY KeyName;
```

[image: union all]

Comment: vladimir - fantastic work with all the research. Could you possibly add one more? i.e. with the temp table created on top. I am hoping it would be fast enough. Please refer my answer..

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti, if you save intermediary aggregated results explicitly into a temp table, you would definitely scan the main table only once. There is some overhead in writing these results to disk and reading them back, but if the main query is complex, it may be better to do it your way, i.e. to split the overly complex query into simpler steps. If there is a lot of data and queries are complex, then having explicit temp table opens possibilities to tune it further by adding indexes to the temp table. Ultimately, different approaches should be compared with real production data and hardware.

Comment: That's true. I am big fan of temp table. Especially indexed ones. They almost negate the little overhead they cause in terms of the gains they offer. And the all-time true answer - *it depends!*

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBaranov , it worked like a charm. Helped me save a lot of effort

Answer (score 2):

A very simplified version of what you want would be the below using `UNION` operator.

```
select CAST('Concat ( col1,col2, "sum")' AS VARCHAR(50)) Key, value
from
(
Select col1, col2, sum(col3) [value]
From Table
Group by col1,col2
)A

UNION ALL

select CAST('Concat (col1,col2, " count")' AS VARCHAR(50)), value
from
(
Select col1, col2, count(col4) [value]
From Table
Group by col1,col2
)B
```

**EDIT**
You can also compute it once and use it later for better performance.

```
Select col1, col2, sum(col3) sumval, count(col4) countval
into #Table
From Table
Group by col1,col2

select CAST('Concat ( col1,col2, "sum")' AS VARCHAR(50)) Key, sumval
from #Table    
UNION ALL 
select CAST('Concat (col1,col2, " count")' AS VARCHAR(50)), countval
from #Table
```

Comment: Yeah, I also thought of union first, But I am not sure if there is going to be a performance impact of this. As I have around 15 analytics which I have to calculate. so it will be 15 union statements that I will have to make ?

Comment: `UNION` is generally considered to be a fast operation. If you still want to gain some performance benefit, you can compute the result once and re-use it down the line.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for as how can I calculate it once and then show the result in the above format so that it can be persisted directly. Otherwise I will have to handle all such operations outside db.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I have used temp table. You can, if your constraints allow, create a physical table with necessary indices in place. You can even create indices on temp tables for better speed.